# Is an incident recorded when an outbreak occurs?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

If a city has no supply cubes and 3 plague cubes, and its card is drawn during the Infect phase of a turn, it outbreaks and affects adjacent locations. The wording in the manual indicates

> To infect a city... If the city has no supply cubes, instead place a plague cube and record the incident. If the city already has 3 plague cubes, do not place a 4th cube.

So, if it already has 3 plague cubes, it specifically says not to place a 4th, but it doesn't say not to record the incident.

In the section on incidents, however, the manual states

> An incident happens whenever a plague cube is placed into a location. Move the incident marker forward 1 space on the incident track.

So this says to only record an incident if a plague cube is placed.

How should I handle the outbreak city itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You do not increase the incident track.**

You've already cited the rule here, which is pretty specific: ***"An incident happens whenever a plague cube is placed into a location."*** If a city has three plague cubes, you aren't placing a new plague cube, so the incident rate will not increase.

[A compiled FAQ on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1807785/compiled-faq-spoilers-hidden) also has this to say (emphasis mine):

> Incident marker: Always remember to move the incident marker *when placing a plague cube on the board.*

Also, [this forum](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1869793/moving-incident-marker-after-outbreak) and [this forum](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1880089/incidents-and-outbreaks) on BGG agree with the literal interpretation of the rules that you allude to.